# Trouble updating one cell in my MySQL DB?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a google maps web application for a game where the user will click a google map marker, make a selection in the window that pops up and click submit. It uses AJAX to update the database with information selected by the user. The database is pre-populated with names of the markers and GPS coordinates, which are loaded. The markers are also placed accordingly upon load via XML.

I'm having trouble updating one row with the user selected information when it's submitted. Currently, a user can select and submit something, but it will update everything in that row for all of the markers; when I just want it to update the field for the corresponding marker that the user submitted it for. I'm unsure on the correct `WHERE` statement to use. Here's my current SQL statement, I'm trying to update a row called `quest`.

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE markers SET quest= '$questName'  WHERE markerName = '$markerName'");
```

Here is my relevant `ajax.php`:

```
<?php 
include("connect.php");
require("call.php");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();     
} else  {   

} 

$markerName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['markerName']);
$questName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['questName']);
$lat = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['lat']);
$longg = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['longg']);
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE markers SET quest= '$questName'  WHERE markerName = '$markerName'");
mysqli_close($con);
```

Here is my relevant call file as well:

```
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    global $dom, $node, $parnode;
    // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
    $node    = $dom->createElement("marker");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
    $newnode->setAttribute("markerName", $row['markerName']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("quest", $row['quest']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("longg", $row['longg']);
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

<s>The error message tells you to look at `ajax.php` at line 7.</s>

Make sure that there is key `markerName` in `$_GET` variable.

Try to pass query string `markerName` when calling `ajax.php`.

**Update**

Make sure that record with specified `markerName` exists in database.

Comment: I've fixed the error, but my DB still isn't updating correctly

Comment: Try to find out actual SQL query sent to MySQL to understand what went wrong

Comment: log the SQL statement you want to execute to a file and then try that to execute using the mysql cli. Then you can exclude the SQL code if that works fine